How do I view my currently active Operation?
When selecting a mission in Helldivers 2, I got a message saying "Warning: Starting a new Operation will abandon your currently active Operation".
What does this mean? How do I check my currently active Operation?


I think your current operation is marked as a green zone on the planet, with yellow being available and white markers being other folks games.

When you select a mission, instead of joining an on-going mission, you are presented with operations to complete. These are sets of 1 to 4 missions, depending difficulty level.
When you open the Galactic Map, it should show you last active operation you have had selected. Operation is considered to be completed when all missions are completed, or at least one fails.

I don't see my last active operation on the Galactic Map unfortunately.
